# Sort List of List of MyType

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

Thanks to eran, I have the following Lambda which creates a list of list of myType. MyType contains a field named `dateOfContainer`.
My question now would be if there is a possibility to extends the expression in order to sort the `List<MyType>` of `List<List<MyType>>` list by `dateOfContainer`?

```
List<List<MyType>> list = new ArrayList<> (
myList.stream().collect (Collectors.groupingBy(MyType::getDateOfContainer)).values());
```

[EDIT]

Thanks a lot for the suggestions. Iam still fighting witch this expression. My current expression looks like this:

```
List<List<ScheduleIntervalContainer>> list = new ArrayList<>(
             structuredScheduleIntervalContainers.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(ScheduleIntervalContainer::getDateOfContainer))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ScheduleIntervalContainer::getDateOfContainer, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList())).values());
```

but I am getting this error in eclipse:

> The method `sorted(Comparator<? super List<ScheduleIntervalContainer>>)` in the type `Stream<List<ScheduleIntervalContainer>>` is not applicable for the arguments `(Comparator<ScheduleIntervalContainer>)`

Comment: Seems that you're trying to sort the result of the previous solution. Instead you should just throw away the previous result and use my solution directly on the input `myList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may sort the stream prior grouping, then use `LinkedHashMap` which preserves order:

```
List<List<MyType>> list = new ArrayList<> (
    myList.stream()
          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyType::getDateOfContainer))
          .collect(
              Collectors.groupingBy(MyType::getDateOfContainer,
                  LinkedHashMap::new,
                  Collectors.toList()))
          .values());
```

Answer (score 1):

Stream has the sorted method which sort the elements. Take a look at the following example:

```
Stream.of(1,2,4,0,3).sorted().forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

This will print

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

But in your case probably you will have to implement your own comparison method to sort the elements. Take a look at the following example I took from http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/

```
Stream.of("d2", "a2", "b1", "b3", "c")
      .sorted((s1, s2) -> {
          System.out.printf("sort: %s; %s\n", s1, s2);
          return s1.compareTo(s2);
      })
      .filter(s -> {
          System.out.println("filter: " + s);
          return s.startsWith("a");
      })
      .map(s -> {
          System.out.println("map: " + s);
          return s.toUpperCase();
      })
      .forEach(s -> System.out.println("forEach: " + s));
```